# C# trying to make labels (Object) bounce from one side of the form to the other

Tags: c#, object, parent-child

I'm currently reading Head First C# third edition, and I'm using visual studio 2015 as an IDE.  One of the programs in the book is called bouncing labels.

**Desired Result:** In the program, an array of 3 label objects correspond to buttons on a form. When each of the labels respective buttons are pressed, the label should then move from one end of the form, to the other like a "bounce".

**Issue:** The labels move to the right end of the form, and then stop 3/4 of the way through the form. They never bounce back. See link for image. (rep is too low to inline)

https://postimg.org/image/qn7s9pfdz/

**Some Technical Details:** The form has a timer, that is enabled to **true** and has an **Interval** of 1. The timer is suppose to cycle the array of bouncers, and if they are not null then to call their move method.

I've included a link to the page in the book which I am learning from.

https://books.google.com/books?id=mcWDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=bouncing+labels+c%23&source=bl&ots=U219enVOgQ&sig=9joHw7tNrCcM8d6rLZDR1ydFsBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiizKqZw-7QAhUFWSYKHQnXAmQQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=bouncing%20labels%20c%23&f=false

I have a script for a Bouncer class, and the form.

Bouncer Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bouncinglabels
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    class LabelBouncer
    {
        public Label MyLabel;
        public bool GoingForward = true;

        public void Move()
        {
            if (MyLabel != null) 
            {
                if (GoingForward == true)
                {
                    MyLabel.Left += 5;
                }
                if (MyLabel.Left >= MyLabel.Parent.Width - MyLabel.Width)
                {
                    GoingForward = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MyLabel.Left -= 5;
                if (MyLabel.Left <= 0)
                {
                    GoingForward = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Form1.Cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bouncinglabels
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        LabelBouncer[] bouncers = new LabelBouncer[3];

        private void ToggleBouncing(int index, Label labelToBounce)
        {
            if (bouncers[index]==null)
            {
                bouncers[index] = new LabelBouncer();
                bouncers[index].MyLabel = labelToBounce;
            }
            else
            {
                bouncers[index] = null;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleBouncing(0, label1);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleBouncing(1, label2);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ToggleBouncing(2, label3);
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (bouncers[i] != null)
                {
                    bouncers[i].Move();
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just moved your else Statement up. You had your else below your if with MyLabel != null.

```
namespace Bouncinglabels
{
using System.Windows.Forms;
class LabelBouncer
{
    public Label MyLabel;
    public bool GoingForward = true;

    public void Move()
    {
        if (MyLabel != null) 
        {
            if (GoingForward)
            {
                MyLabel.Left += 5;
            }
            else
            {
               MyLabel.Left -= 5;
               if (MyLabel.Left <= 0)
               {
                   GoingForward = true;
               }
            }
            if (MyLabel.Right >= MyLabel.Parent.Width)
            {
                GoingForward = false;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you! I can see the logic, however I'm wondering why they wrote it the way they did in the book sample.  I can't find any confirmed errata